# Automatic toctree update

Tags: directory, python-sphinx, glob, toctree

I'm not sure if this is possible. But I'm hoping to put multiple .rst files in a directory, and during compilation. I want these files to automatically be inserted in the `toctree`. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `glob` option which enables wildcards. Like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :glob:

   *
```

This adds all other *.rst files in the same directory to the toctree.

Reference: [*"Use “globbing” in toctree directives"*](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree)